Avoid nullability warning/error when enabling CS8602
Consider the following helper method which comes from a legacy codebase
public static class ListHelper
{
    public static bool HasAny<T>(this IReadOnlyCollection<T>? list)
    {
        return list != null && list.Count > 0;
    }
}

Consider the following use case
List<string>? fileNames2 = null;

if (fileNames2.HasAny())
{
    var aasd = fileNames2[0]; // CS8602 Dereference of a possibly null reference.
}

Using .net 8 as target framework with nullable set to enable, this code will generate a warning or error depending on the configured severity of CS8602. Is it possible to avoid getting this warning/error as null is clearly handled in the extension method and will never be null inside the if condition?
Severity    Code    Description
Error (active)  CS8602  Dereference of a possibly null reference.

The following would solve the problem but beats the purpose of having the extension method:
if (fileNames2?.Any() == true)
{
    var aasd = fileNames2[0];
}

